# permutations for pass generation

Tags: c, char

From this original code which generates all possible combinations of 3 numbers:

```
void gen(char *word, char *chars, int ug, int length) {
    size_t i = 0;
    int u = ug;
    while(i < strlen(chars)){
        word[u] = chars[i++];

        if(u < (length-1)) {
            gen(word, chars, ++u, length);
            u--;
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char *chars = "0123456789";
    /* 3 char long */
    int i = 3;

    int length = 3;
    /* Allocate memory for the output */
    char *word = calloc(length, 0);

    gen(word, chars, 0, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

But cause I need the function to work differently, I modified it like this:

```
char *genpass(char* pass,int len, int crt, size_t i) {
    char *chars = "0123456789";
    pass[crt] = chars[i++];
    return pass;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *pass = calloc(10, 0);
    int crt;//current permutation
    int len = 3;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (crt=0;crt<10;crt++)
    {
        pass = genpass(pass,len,crt,i);
        printf("pass: %s\n", pass);
        i++;
        //some other code to work with pass
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But now it returns:

```
pass: 0
pass: 01
pass: 012
pass: 0123
pass: 01234
pass: 012345
pass: 0123456
pass: 01234567
pass: 012345678
pass: 0123456789
```

***What did I mess up? How can I make it generate correctly first 10 permutations of 3 length numbers?***

Comment: In what way does the original need to act differently? If you look at your new `gen` function, it doesn't even refer to the `len` parameter, and it just keeps bumping the index into `chars` array, thus giving you ever increasing substrings of `chars`.

Comment: the original function is cycling thru void so I removed that part. I want on each append of the function to generate only one pass not all at once

Comment: anyone with a useful hint or answer??

Comment: You asked in your post, "What did I mess up?" If you look at your new `genpass` function, it just continues to add a character to the end of `pass` after each call. The loop you call it from iterates from indices 0 to 9 doing this. So the output you are seeing is fairly predictable.

Comment: can you give me a hint about how to replace the cycling of gen(word, chars, ++u, length); ? I wanna transform the void into a char function and that void cycling is killing me

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "3 length numbers"?

Comment: 000,001,002 ... 100,101 ... 205,206,207 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Now your function genpass() is not recursive!

If you want to only generate 10 permutations, look in your code when you printf something and increment a counter each time you printf a permutation, and when the counter is 10 break the while

Comment: I did that with for loop

Comment: what do you want as result?

0123456789

0123456798
...

?

Comment: no, 000,001,002,003...010,011...100,101 but not all at once. only the number of permutation I set up. (crt in this case)

Comment: and all chars must be permutated

Comment: something like permutations of 10 taken by 3

Comment: so you want: for (i) 0..3 for(j) 0..3 for(k) 0..3 (print ijk) ?